# Is it possible to add a horizontal line to an infragistics ultraSparkLine that isn't an average

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I am new to using infragistic controls. I have added a ultraSparkLine to a VB 2017 application. I am doing it using in Area format. It is displaying work being accomplished during time frame. Want I would like to do is add a horizontal line that would show target rate of what is expected as work rate. I see I can have the Trendline but that seems to show average work rate for time frame being displayed.

Is it possible to add a horizontal line at a predetermined value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in way to draw horizontal line. However you can use normal range to make something like a horizontal line. First set [minimum](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~minimum) and [maximum](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~maximum) to your chart. This will allow you to show the horizontal line above/bellow the spark line. Then set [NormalRangeMaximum](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~normalrangemaximum) and [NormalRangeMinimum](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~normalrangeminimum) to some very close values. For example if minimum is 0 and maximum is 100 I would set the ranges to let say 89.9 and 90.
As a final touch you can set [NormalRangeFill](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~infragistics.win.datavisualization.ultrasparkline~normalrangefill) to some brush as needed in your application.